# D3 Problems with merge and adding labels to siblings

Tags: d3.js

I was trying to add labels to circles that are constantly moving in D3. One of the ways I found was to insert the label and the circle to a `g` tag. However, this causes errors whenever I want to EXIT the elements and merge them (which is not happening right now).

Is there any other way to do it? My graph right now seems to be with lower frames per second because it is not using the merge to update from the current x/y position to the new one.

The code is as follow:

```
var t = d3.transition()
    .duration(0);

// JOIN new data with old elements.
var circles = g.append("g").selectAll('g')
    .data(data.values)
    .enter()
    .append('g')

// EXIT elements
d3.selectAll("circle").transition()
    .attr("class", "exit")
    .remove();
// EXIT elements
d3.selectAll(".label")
    .attr("class", "exit")
    .remove();

// ENTER new elements present in new data.
// Circles
circles.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "enter")
    .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.country); })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.active_cases); })
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.total_deaths) })
    .merge(circles)
    .transition(t)
    .attr("r", 15)


// Labels
circles.append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("font-size", 10)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.total_deaths) })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return 3 + y(d.active_cases) })
    .merge(circles)
    .text(function (d) { return d.country })
```

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using?

Comment: The latest version

Comment: You might want to follow the method illustrated here: https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join

Comment: Unfortunately, If I follow exactly that, I will end up with the same problem as the one above. The new .join() function changes mostly the syntax but not the way to do the UPDATE, EXIT and JOIN.

Comment: The code portion shared in the question appears to be missing `.exit()`.

Comment: In this particular case, the .exit() does not work in the code. It would not remove the circles from it